# R: submitButton and conditionalPanel

Tags: r, shiny

I've got a UI that is entirely build with conditional panels. But the problem I am having now is that I need a submit button. When introducing the submit button, it will render all the conditional UI to not show up conditionally unless I press the submit button.

My question is if there is a way so that the conditional display of various UI sliders, input, etc be not dependent on the submit button?

Thanks,

Comment: would be good if you included a minimal version of your code, and what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem when I was using the submit button to crunch data intensive code that was dependent on the widgets I programmed on the reactive interface. As soon as I added a submit button, all reactive widgets became static until i pressed the submit button (which was a pain because I had a reactive plot on the main panel). Thanks to the wonderful Mr. Cheng, I found out that you cannot (yet) make individual widgets dependent on a submit button. It is an all or nothing kind of deal. Therefore it may better to use an 'actionButton', sandwiched between the 'observe' and 'isolate' functions. It may look something like this..

```
observe({
if (input$action_button == 0) # tells action button to do nothing when not clicked ..
  return()
isolate({ # this isolates the code you want to execute when clicking the action button..
###some function or conditional panel###
})})
```

Hopefully this works for you. It did for me :)

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code because it does not work somehow for me? My code is to long for a comment